# Woocommerce JSON data is not showing in collection view

Tags: ios, arrays, json, alamofire

**

> i was trying to load woo commerce product list in my collection view.
>   i am gating data from server also able to print data. but when i go to
>   showing data in my collection view cell it's not showing.

**

here what i have done

```
var newArraivalArray = [AnyObject]()
```

Here i try to get Json data array

```
  Alamofire.request("https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?after=2016-12-19T16:39:57-08:00", parameters:
            ["consumer_key":"*******", "consumer_secret":"*******"])
            .responseJSON{  response in

          if let json = response.result.value {
                    newArraivalArray = json as! [AnyObject]
                    print(json)
                }
      self.collectionView.reloadData()

}
```

for number of item in collectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return newArraivalArray.count
}
```

for showing data in collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cellC = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NewArraivelCollectionViewCell
 let productName = newArraivalArray[indexPath.row]["name"]
           cellC.name.text = productName as? String

return cellC
}
```

but i did't see any data in my collection view cell.but some how product name is not showing in my cell. i have no idea what happening.

here what error i get [image]

Here is my json Data

```
[
      {
            "id": 57678,
            "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt",
            "slug": "mens-formal-printed-shirt-3",
            "permalink": "https://infinitymegamall.com/product/mens-formal-printed-shirt-3/",
            "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:29:58",
            "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:29:58",
            "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:29:58",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:29:58",
            "type": "variable",
            "status": "publish",
            "featured": false,
            "catalog_visibility": "visible",
            "description": "<p>Code:-4105110568</p>\n",
            "short_description": "<p>Code:-4105110568</p>\n",
            "sku": "4105110568",
            "price": "1971",
            "regular_price": "",
            "sale_price": "",
            "date_on_sale_from": null,
            "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
            "date_on_sale_to": null,
            "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
            "price_html": "<div class=\"product-price\"><del><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#2547;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;2,190.00</span></del> <ins><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#2547;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;1,971.00</span></ins></div>",
            "on_sale": true,
            "purchasable": true,
            "total_sales": 0,
            "virtual": false,
            "downloadable": false,
            "downloads": [],
            "download_limit": -1,
            "download_expiry": -1,
            "external_url": "",
            "button_text": "",
            "tax_status": "taxable",
            "tax_class": "",
            "manage_stock": false,
            "stock_quantity": null,
            "in_stock": true,
            "backorders": "no",
            "backorders_allowed": false,
            "backordered": false,
            "sold_individually": false,
            "weight": "",
            "dimensions": {
                "length": "",
                "width": "",
                "height": ""
            },
            "shipping_required": true,
            "shipping_taxable": true,
            "shipping_class": "",
            "shipping_class_id": 0,
            "reviews_allowed": true,
            "average_rating": "0.00",
            "rating_count": 0,
            "related_ids": [
                47912,
                47785,
                47886,
                48373,
                48708
            ],
            "upsell_ids": [],
            "cross_sell_ids": [],
            "parent_id": 0,
            "purchase_note": "",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 220,
                    "name": "Full Sleeve",
                    "slug": "full-sleeve-casual"
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "name": "Men",
                    "slug": "men"
                },
                {
                    "id": 53,
                    "name": "Shirt",
                    "slug": "shirt"
                },
                {
                    "id": 91,
                    "name": "Casual",
                    "slug": "casual"
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": 57683,
                    "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:25:13",
                    "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:25:13",
                    "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:25:13",
                    "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:25:13",
                    "src": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Mens-Formal-Printed-Shirt-Sky-Print-4105110568-2190tk-2.png",
                    "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt-Sky Print&#8212;&#8211;4105110568&#8212;-2,190tk (2)",
                    "alt": "",
                    "position": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 57684,
                    "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:25:33",
                    "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:25:33",
                    "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:25:33",
                    "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:25:33",
                    "src": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Mens-Formal-Printed-Shirt-Sky-Print-4105110568-2190tk-1.png",
                    "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt-Sky Print&#8212;&#8211;4105110568&#8212;-2,190tk (1)",
                    "alt": "",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Size",
                    "position": 0,
                    "visible": true,
                    "variation": true,
                    "options": [
                        "L",
                        "M",
                        "XL"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default_attributes": [],
            "variations": [
                57682,
                57680,
                57681
            ],
            "grouped_products": [],
            "menu_order": 0,
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 481056,
                    "key": "_vc_post_settings",
                    "value": {
                        "vc_grid_id": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 481216,
                    "key": "des_content",
                    "value": "Code:-4105110568"
                },
                {
                    "id": 481217,
                    "key": "trending_product",
                    "value": "off"
                },
                {
                    "id": 481269,
                    "key": "post_views",
                    "value": "3"
                }
            ],
            "_links": {
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/57678"
                    }
                ],
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 57672,
            "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt",
            "slug": "mens-formal-printed-shirt-2",
            "permalink": "https://infinitymegamall.com/product/mens-formal-printed-shirt-2/",
            "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:12:29",
            "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:12:29",
            "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:12:29",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:12:29",
            "type": "variable",
            "status": "publish",
            "featured": false,
            "catalog_visibility": "visible",
            "description": "<p>Code:-4105110563</p>\n",
            "short_description": "<p>Code:-4105110563</p>\n",
            "sku": "4105110563",
            "price": "1971",
            "regular_price": "",
            "sale_price": "",
            "date_on_sale_from": null,
            "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
            "date_on_sale_to": null,
            "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
            "price_html": "<div class=\"product-price\"><del><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#2547;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;2,190.00</span></del> <ins><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#2547;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;1,971.00</span></ins></div>",
            "on_sale": true,
            "purchasable": true,
            "total_sales": 0,
            "virtual": false,
            "downloadable": false,
            "downloads": [],
            "download_limit": -1,
            "download_expiry": -1,
            "external_url": "",
            "button_text": "",
            "tax_status": "taxable",
            "tax_class": "",
            "manage_stock": false,
            "stock_quantity": null,
            "in_stock": true,
            "backorders": "no",
            "backorders_allowed": false,
            "backordered": false,
            "sold_individually": false,
            "weight": "",
            "dimensions": {
                "length": "",
                "width": "",
                "height": ""
            },
            "shipping_required": true,
            "shipping_taxable": true,
            "shipping_class": "",
            "shipping_class_id": 0,
            "reviews_allowed": true,
            "average_rating": "0.00",
            "rating_count": 0,
            "related_ids": [
                48222,
                48373,
                47892,
                50683,
                48377
            ],
            "upsell_ids": [],
            "cross_sell_ids": [],
            "parent_id": 0,
            "purchase_note": "",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 220,
                    "name": "Full Sleeve",
                    "slug": "full-sleeve-casual"
                },
                {
                    "id": 37,
                    "name": "Men",
                    "slug": "men"
                },
                {
                    "id": 53,
                    "name": "Shirt",
                    "slug": "shirt"
                },
                {
                    "id": 91,
                    "name": "Casual",
                    "slug": "casual"
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": 57676,
                    "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:07:45",
                    "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:07:45",
                    "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:07:45",
                    "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:07:45",
                    "src": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Mens-Formal-Printed-Shirt-Maroon-4105110563-2190tk-2.png",
                    "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt-Maroon&#8212;&#8212;4105110563&#8212;-2,190tk (2)",
                    "alt": "",
                    "position": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 57677,
                    "date_created": "2018-01-10T18:08:25",
                    "date_created_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:08:25",
                    "date_modified": "2018-01-10T18:08:25",
                    "date_modified_gmt": "2018-01-10T12:08:25",
                    "src": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Mens-Formal-Printed-Shirt-Maroon-4105110563-2190tk-1.png",
                    "name": "Mens Formal Printed Shirt-Maroon&#8212;&#8212;4105110563&#8212;-2,190tk (1)",
                    "alt": "",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Size",
                    "position": 0,
                    "visible": true,
                    "variation": true,
                    "options": [
                        "L",
                        "M",
                        "XL"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default_attributes": [],
            "variations": [
                57673,
                57674,
                57675
            ],
            "grouped_products": [],
            "menu_order": 0,
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 480903,
                    "key": "_vc_post_settings",
                    "value": {
                        "vc_grid_id": []
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 481053,
                    "key": "des_content",
                    "value": "Code:-4105110563"
                },
                {
                    "id": 481054,
                    "key": "trending_product",
                    "value": "off"
                },
                {
                    "id": 481055,
                    "key": "post_views",
                    "value": "3"
                }
            ],
            "_links": {
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/57672"
                    }
                ],
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://infinitymegamall.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Is your collection view correctly setup  up ? like cell identifier & class & etc

Comment: yes.... all are ok